# Open popup with menu and redirect to external adress

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hello again Stackoverflow!

I want to create a chrome application, that when you open it, it will open a popup with a menu, where you can click on some links, and when  you click on a certain link a new tab will open and you get to that adress. But its not working, when i click on the menu link nothing happens. So here is what i've got:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "menu",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "menu",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "menu.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "notifications"]
}
```

menu.html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('redirect/google.html')}, function(tab) {
    });
});">hey</a>
```

redirect/google.html:

```
<script>window.location="http://google.com"</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking way too hard, i could've just do:

```
<a href="#" onclick="chrome.tabs.create({url:'http://google.com'});">Google</a>
```